# Unable to create initial extent for segment in tablespace xxx, even though tablespace has enough free space

Tags: database, plsql, oracle11g, database-administration

I am dealing with this daily batch procedure, which is time and again throwing the above error during Insertion procedures in the batch. 
The specified tablespace currently contained 5 datafiles, all only 40-50% occupied. But sometimes while trying to run insertion query we get "Unable to create initial extent..". Currently the problem is being solved by adding datafiles because of batch urgency, due to which almost half of the datafile space seems to be wasted.

I do not have enough privileges to run SYS DBA queries, but I need to come up with every possible reason of such behavior. For now, I have following informations

Table space is autoextensible.
No. of datafiles: 6 (recently added one during batch issue)
Each datafile size: 29.3 GB
Blocks:   3,840,000
Increment by: 100 MB
Max size: 29.3 GB

With my research, such problem might be due to fragmentation in the tablespace [ the most solid conclusion I have reached till now]. Could there be any other potential cause?

Comment: How big is the initial extent it's trying to create, and what is it trying to create a segment for - a new table or index (which would be odd), a partition, ...?

Comment: Is this tablespace also specified as the temp tablespace?

Comment: I have to say, this sounds like a case of fighting the last war, which I'll define as worrying about the cost of that "unused" disk space instead of the cost of not having the disk space available for use when needed. The cost of the "unused" disk space is fixed and easily calculable, and is probably pretty low (PC disk space now costs less than $0.25/GB). The cost of a job crashing and being re-started is variable, tougher to figure out, but IMO probably higher, especially when you factor in people's time and the cost of late information. YMMV. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to know is that even if you freed some space inside your tablespaces, this space isn't released to the system. There are possibility to shrink the tablesapces and diminish fragmentation within them. Here is what you should check in such a case:

1. The tablespace's size is limited; this limit can be extended.
2. There is no more space on the file system

   - check the db file size; e.g. on [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) do a `df -g /my_db/path/`
   - note in some cases the above doesn't give 100%, even though a process is still locking the disk space and must be killed for the space to be really released.